# Wordpress htaccess to redict subdomain on sub folder

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My public html folder has 2 subfolders: `./en` and `./fr`.
My main domain is .com domain, it currently lands in the root of `public_html` folder (I am using bluehost and the cPanel is opened with the mydomain.com as primary domain in this cPanel).
I have opened a subdomain fr.mydomain.com which I want my visitors to be redirect to the `./fr` subfolder.
I am using wordpress in `./en` folder and another wordpress in `./fr` folder.
I want mydomain.com to fall into the `./en` folder and fr.mydomain.com to fall into the `./fr` folder.

How should I setup .htaccess of the public root folder ?
How should I setup .htaccess of the `/en` folder ?
How should I setup .htaccess of the `/fr` folder ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to rewrite based on the `HTTP Host`.

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} en.example.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/en/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} fr.example.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/fr/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```